# GitHub Rest API transfer ownership

Tags: git, rest, powershell, github

I am trying to transfer ownership for a repository using PowerShell.

This is how it looks my JSON:

```
$owner ='x'
$project ='test'

$transfer = '{
  "new_owner": "xyz"
}'
```

I POST using :

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://git.bfl.local/api/v3/repos/$owner/$project/transfer" -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Body $transfer
```

I get this error:

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.9/v3"}
```

I followed this guide: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#transfer-a-repository

```
$Token ='istuc:xxx'
$Based64Token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([char[]]$Token);

$headers = @{
    "Authorization" = 'Basic {0}' -f $Based64Token;
    "Accept" = "application/vnd.github.nightshade-preview+json";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
}
```

Comment: Could you post the headers sans any sensitive information?

Comment: sure...i edited